# How to get the %like% operator to be case insensitive

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way to turn the `%like%` operator in the `datatable` package to be case insensitive ? So for instance `'hello' %like% 'HELlo'` would match.

Comment: You could use `%chin%` instead of `%like%` or if it is a substring match, then use `grepl` which has `ignore.case` command

Comment: You can also use `tolower`: `tolower(a) %like% tolower(b)`.

Comment: @nicola good idea thanks

Comment: you can also look into `str_to_lower` from the `stringr` package or `tidyverse`. It also works with translations using the `locale` argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By not relying on the definition in `data.table`:

```
`%like%` <- function (x, pattern) { 
  stringi::stri_detect_regex(x, pattern, case_insensitive=TRUE)
}
```

`data.table` defines it as:

```
function (vector, pattern) 
{
    if (is.factor(vector)) {
        as.integer(vector) %in% grep(pattern, levels(vector))
    }
    else {
        grepl(pattern, vector)
    }
}
```

You could cover the `factor` case if you like but it's not a very complex function. No "magic" in it.

I use `stringi` as it is (for my work) far more robust than built-in string ops and provides a great deal more power under the hood.

You can also define it as:

```
`%like%` <- function (x, pattern) { 
  grepl(pattern, x, ignore.case=TRUE)
}
```

(again, ignoring the `factor` case) if you like. You lose the vectorized `pattern` doing this, tho.

Make the name `%likeic%` (like, ignore case) if you don't want to squash the definition for `data.table`'s `%like%`.

Comment: lesson being: `%like%` is a convenience function, which means it's designed for very common but simple situations. The real workhorse is `grepl`, which has more robust features; and `stringi` provides an even more powerful `grepl`

Comment: What would be a use case for a vectorized pattern? and when you say you 'lose' that, you mean, it's in the stringi version, is this correct?